# SQL Server index performance

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, indexing

I'm interested in databases and have started to play around with SQL Server 2008, I've read that using appropriate Indexes on tables can help to improve the overall performance of the database.

I have two tables and auto generated 1 million rows in each table using SQL Data Generator, Table 1 is a customers table and Table 2 is a renters table, the designs are as follows:

```
Customer                                    Renters
CustomerID (PK)                             RentersID (PK)
ForeName (Non clustered index)              StartDate
SurName                                     EndDate
Email                                       RentalNights
                                            CustomerID (FK) (Non Clustered index)
```

I've read that placing a non clustered index on the most commonly used columns as well as foreign key columns will help to improve performance.  I created a simple join query before using indexes and after using indexes, but for me I can't seen the increased performance when using indexes, can any body help me out?  The images below are the execution plans before indexes and after using them.

Before Indexes:
[image]

After Indexes:
[image]

**EDIT:**
this is the SQL syntax i am using

```
SELECT cu.ForeName + ' ' + cu.SurName AS 'Name' 
FROM dbo.Customers cu
INNER JOIN dbo.Renters re ON re.CustomerID = cu.CustomerID
WHERE cu.ForeName = 'Daniel'
```

**EDIT**
This is my index syntax using the ones posted in the reply below:

`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_Customer] ON [dbo].[Customers] 
(
    [ForeName] ASC,
    [CustomerID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [SurName]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO`

Comment: Can you please also show the **SQL query** that lead to these execution plans?

Comment: Also show the code for the indexes?

Comment: Also it does look like you are using your indexes, is the performance the same?  does it take the same time to run both queries?

Comment: Hey JNK, yeh the performance is the same and so are the timings, im just looking for a way to improve the timing etc when a name is searched for

Comment: @Peter please post your index syntax, and let me know if you have tried the ones I included in my answer below.

Comment: @JNK i have amended my original question with the index create syntax, i have used your suggestions below.

Comment: @Peter and the execution time is still identical?

Comment: It's slightly faster now, so I'm creating more tables and more join etc to see if there is a real improvement in times, execution cost % etc, and it seems to be working!! IT's just taking time to wrap my head around the stats etc and what they mean!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your query the best nonclustered indexes to build would be:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_IndexA on dbo.Customers (Forename, CustomerID) 
     INCLUDE (SurName)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_IndexB on dbo.Renters (CustomerID)
```

You want your key fields to be on your filter or `JOIN` columns, and your `INCLUDE` columns are at the leaf level to get returned in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Hi @JNK, i just wanted to ask you about the INCLUDE (SurName) and what this does as I am not 100% sure?

Comment: @Peter `INCLUDE` keeps the data for the INCLUDED columns in the leaf level of the index but not in the tree - if you think of an index like a phone book, it's keyed on `LastName, Firstname` (how it's sorted) but the leaf level (the entries) has `PhoneNo, Address, Zipcode` data as well.  You can't sort by `PhoneNo` but once you get to the entry you have that data.  In your query you are `SELECT` ing surname but it's not in any of your index keys and you don't sort on it, so I included it.  This avoids a key lookup or bookmark lookup where the engine queries the clustered index for the data.